# Enabling the `todo` feature in sphinx docs

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am trying to use `todo` feature, I found a link on [sphinx-docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/todo.html?highlight=todo#directive-todolist) and the following syntax

```
.. todo::
```

but it says that I need to set the `todo_include_todos` to `True`, as by default it is `False`, which file I need to update to get in enabled?

I found another SO post [Sphinx todo box not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22290548/sphinx-todo-box-not-showing) but don't think it mentions the file where I need to set the config.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`sphinx.ext.todo` is a Sphinx extension which can be enabled by adding it to the list of extensions in your `conf.py`:

```
extensions = [
    'extname',
    'sphinx.ext.todo',
]
```

Once enabled, you need to configure it by setting the value `todo_include_todos` to `True`, also in your `conf.py`:

```
# Display todos by setting to True
todo_include_todos = True
```

Theme support for todos varies.

See also http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-extensions

Answer (score 0):

Note that the configuration option can also be overridden on the command line, which may make it easier to quickly expose or hide "to do"s according to the target audience. I believe booleans have to be passed as `0` or `1` in this case...

```
sphinx-build -b html -D todo_include_todos=1 -c docs docs build/html
```

or

```
python -m sphinx -b html -D todo_include_todos=1 -c docs docs build/html
```